# EXCEL: How to merge cells with certain values

Tags: excel

I have this table on excel

https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2kDS.png

And i want to make looks like this, but to do this for all Column, because i have a lot of rows.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1v0TE.png

Comment: Learn VBA, then code something that loops down a column. The logic here is to store the non-blank cell into a variable and check the current cell iterated on if it's blank. If so, `UNION` it with the stored cell. Otherwise, merge all the cells united so far this way, and assign the new non-blank cell into the variable.

Answer (score 0):

1- Save your spreadsheet enabling macros. (save as .xlsm)
2- Open the view tab, click on macros, view macros and edit
3- Paste the following code:

```
Sub Macro0()
    'I assume your information is in the column A
    With Range("A1:A65000")

    'I also assume all CATEGORIES start with the word CATEGORY
    'If that is not the case you have to define a list with all GATEGORIES
    Set c = .Find("GATEGORY", LookIn:=xlValues)

    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = c.Address
        oneBefore = firstAddress - 1
        Do
            Range("A1", oneBefore).Select
            Selection.Merge
            Set c = .FindNext(c)
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
    End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Please note my comments in the code.
Let me know if it worked for you.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746%28v=office.15%29.aspx